# a4j:ajax listener exception MethodNotFoundException

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, listener, ajax4jsf

I started study RichFaces 4.2.2 and have a problem in simple example, I have an xml:

```
<ui:define name="content">       
        <h:form>
            <rich:panel style="width: 50%">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="Name:"/>
                    <h:inputText id="inp" value="#{echoBean.name}">
                        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="echo count"  listener="#{echoBean.countListener}"/>
                    </h:inputText>

                    <h:outputText value="Echo:"/>
                    <h:outputText id="echo" value="#{echoBean.name}"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Count:"/>
                    <h:outputText id="count" value="#{echoBean.count}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <a4j:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{echoBean.countListener}" render="echo, count"/>
            </rich:panel>
        </h:form>

</ui:define>
```

and a simple bean:

```
@Component("echoBean")
@Scope(value = "session")
public class EchoBean {
private String name;
private Integer count = 0;

//getter setter methods here

public void countListener(ActionEvent event) {
    count++;
    }
}
```

And when i try to print in inputText i have exception:

```
Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /home.xhtml @35,112 listener="#{echoBean.countListener}": Method not found: com.example.training.bean.EchoBean@d523fa.countListener()
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.behavior.MethodExpressionAjaxBehaviorListener.processAjaxBehavior(MethodExpressionAjaxBehaviorListener.java:71)
at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:98)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.behavior.AjaxBehavior.broadcast(AjaxBehavior.java:348)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:763)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
... 19 more
```

But why? With button this same listener works just fine and in docs for "listener" parameter in a4j:ajax it says that:

*The expression must evaluate to a public method that takes an ActionEvent parameter, with a return type of void, or to a public method that takes no arguments with a return type of void*

Why it uses `countListener()` without `ActionEvent` parameter? I don't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you to be able to use the `listener` attribute with RF4, your listener method should take an argument of the `AjaxBehaviorEvent` type, not an `ActionEvent` type. The other alternative approach as you can see from the error message is to define a standard java method that doesn't take arguments and has a void return type as in

```
   public void countListener();
```

> Why it uses countListener() without ActionEvent parameter? I don't get it.

That's the contract for the API, you're required to conform to be able to use it.

Comment: Thx i have read about Faces ActionEvent and didnt find anything about AjaxBehaviourEvent

Answer (score 1):

Use the bean function with the following signature
void as return type
ActionEvent object as parameter
Example for the bean function is as below

```
public void countListener(ActionEvent event) {}
```